# Symfony2 Vhost Configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, php, routing, virtualhost, symfony

I'm new to Symfony2 and following the [EnsJobeet tutorial](http://www.ens.ro/2012/03/22/symfony2-jobeet-day-1-starting-up-the-project/). My VirtualHost config is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jobeet.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ensjobeet/web/
    DirectoryIndex app.php
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/jobeet-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/jobeet-access.log combined
    <Directory "/var/www/ensjobeet/web/">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I make requests to jobeet.local/app_dev.php/job/ I get the jobs page, when I make requests to jobeet.local/app.php/job/ I get the jobs page. However requests to jobeet.local/job/ 404 with `The requested URL /job/ was not found on this server.`

I would have thought that requests jobeet.local/ and jobeet.local/app.php/ would have been equivalent but they don't appear to be so is there some other aspect of the environment configuration I have wrong?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.equation.fr/equablog/2014/08/29/symfony-2-bien-debuter-projet-vhost/) an exemple for prod and dev vhosts

```
# Symfony 2 : monapp.dev
<virtualHost *:80>
  ServerName monapp.dev
  DocumentRoot /data/www/MonApp/web/

    <Directory "/data/www/MonApp/web">
      DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
      Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch
      AllowOverride None
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# Symfony 2 : monapp.prod
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName monapp.prod
  DocumentRoot /data/www/MonApp/web/

    <Directory "/data/www/MonApp/web">
       DirectoryIndex app.php
       Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch
       AllowOverride All
       Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

mod_rewrite was installed but not enabled. Silly me!!

Answer (score 0):

A combination of both files+ ([@Bendihossan](https://serverfault.com/users/77503/bendihossan) and [@Emma](https://serverfault.com/users/241274/emma)) worked here...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName symfony2-7-9.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/symfony2-7-9/web/
    DirectoryIndex app.php
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/symfony2-7-9-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/symfony2-7-9-custom.log combined
    <Directory "/var/www/symfony2-7-9/web/">
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride None
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

After Setting up Virtual Host, put below code into web/.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
    #    RewriteBase /
    #</IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```